# How to create a Show/Hide Button on Contact Related List in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-button, related-list, custom-controller

-Background-

Our contact related lists on the account page layout displays records with one of the following two statuses: "Active" and "Terminated". Users are being overwhelmed with the number of terminated records within the related list and are finding it cumbersome to try and find their desired Active contact.

-Proposal-

Either create one hide/show custom button or two custom buttons that will individual hide and show Terminated records within the related list.

-Issue-

I am new to creating buttons, visualforce pages, controllers, and components within SFDC and would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to tackle this project.

-Request-

I have amassed all of SFDC's beginning guides to the above, but have found nothing that touches the subject of creating a button that will conditionally hide/show records. Have you done something like this before or have advice on what to do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the Salesforce StackExchange. Thanks for all the detail in your question. It is very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

In this scenario, rather than creating some custom code to do that, have you considered just setting a Sort Order on the Status field to group all of your Active `Contacts` at the top of your related list and push your Terminated `Contacts` to the bottom of the list. On your page layout, there is a way to set your `Sort By` field for your related list.

[image: Contact's Related List]

This should solve your problem with no coding needed.

Comment: My initial thought on handling this task was also to sort the related list, but it did not seem to work for my predicament as I cannot make a global change. I can only a change to a specific Record Type and/or a specific Profile. 

Am I wildly missing something?

To give you additional background: 

The org that I walked into proposes a unique structural design issue in that we have multiple firms using the same Org vs Org to Org sharing or other measures. A further wrench into the system is that both our external customers and internal corporate employees are using the same org.

Comment: @Lindsey : were you able to fix this requirement?